# Advice on making a java program that will enable a user to choose a book from a given list, input quantity, and confirm the order

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I'm not asking for the whole code but rather what are the things I need to learn on how to do the program. I need to truly learn how the program works.

I'm a first year college student and we've been only taught java print, input, display, Scanner, and JOptionPane so far. We were tasked to make a program using those what we've only learned.

What I had in mind is, let's say, a student needs to order their school books that's been required. Clicking on the program, the user will see at the top part of the program are the list of the books available with their title, code, price, and available quantity(optional)

Below are the multiple inputs with the first being asking for the code of the book they've chosen. Next is the quantity they want. Confirmation buttons at the bottom "ORDER AGAIN" "CONFIRM ORDER" and "CANCEL". "ORDER AGAIN" will make the user choose another title and quantity. "CONFIRM ORDER" will be the sort of receipt and confirmation page.

Is this program possible to make in Scanner or JOptionPane? Anymore complicated will make the prof suspicious. He's been clear that using **only** what he taught.

If so, what are the steps? Even then I still have a vague idea on how the program will look like given my limited and restricted knowledge.

Comment: What it looks like is that he expects you to make a class to represent books and maybe orders as well. For the book's code being input and the quantity I'd imagine you could use the showInputDialog method to take in the user string, and parse it into the type you want it to be. For the menu with "cancel, order again..."  I would look at showOptionDialog. You could test the option they chose and perform the action from there.

Answer (score 0):

We certainly can't write this program for you, but asking for advice is OK.
Think about what you need to accomplish. 
  1. Display a list of books
  2. User selects some item from the list, and a quantity
  3. confirm the order

So in order to do #1...
  You will need a list (array) of books
  You will need to display that, probably in the JOptionPane
  You will probably do that by using a `FOR LOOP` (or `FOR EACH LOOP`) over the array,
  and printing it out.

So in order to do #2...
  You will need to have the program accept user input, probably via a scanner
  You will probably need a print statement asking them for their input, and if
  they would like to continue. Something like:
  You will need an array that is the SAME SIZE (i.e., the same # of elements)
  as the book array.

```
  (java/python pseudocode format, not intended to function):
    print("Please select a book")
    print(bookarray)
    Scanner captures user input
    print("How many?")
    Scanner captures user input
    print("Would you like anything else? y/n")
    if Scanner.input = "y", repeat the process
    else: print ("thank you for your order")
```

So in order to do #3...
  You will need to know how many of each book was purchased.
  Say you have a `bookArray like = {"Book1", "Book2", "Book3"}`
  You could have a `SalesArray like = {0,0,0}`
  Then, as someone orders a book, you could grab the `INDEX` from the bookarray
  and update the SalesArray accordingly

Loop through the book array and print out the book name, and associated sales
  from the sales array

It helps for these types of projects to THINK about what you have to do. Once you start writing code,
  if you get stuck, post questions that have not already been answered to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it is possible.

The easiest solution for you would probably be to let the buttons and all the other fancy stuff out and just try to get the programm working first.

Maybe create input similiar to text adventures (oregan trail and whatnot). By printing and reading from the console.
Start by outputting a formated list of the books, title, code etc. Then ask the user what book he wants and read his input (book, quantity, ...) from the console. Maybe display an acknowledgement and ask if he wants to continue.

Once the core is working you can work out all the fancier stuff.